# what is difference between 'gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf' and 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc'?

Tags: linux, cmake, cross-compiling

gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/artful/arm64/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
Is 'gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi' Command replaced by 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' now?
but I can still '$locate gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi'to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf` - Ubuntu package name

`arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` - binary name, installed by the package